# python garbage collector windows vs ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, garbage-collection

I have a python script that reads files in multiple threads and saves the content to a DB.

This works fine in windows and stays at around 500M Memory Usage.

However the same program builds up memory usage to the maximum available value (14GB) and basically kills the machine.

Could this be a garbage collection problem?

Comment: how are you reading the files?

Comment: It's actually read from a url:  
res = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=15)
html = res.read()

Comment: The badness is on ubuntu?

Comment: CPython doesn't have a garbage collector like .NET or the JVM. It uses reference counting to immediately free objects and their resources when the reference count drops to 0. Try `gc.collect()` to see whether breaking reference cycles and clearing some of the internal freelists helps, which is especially the case if one of the freed objects was acting as a high-water mark that prevented the heap from shrinking.

Comment: Same here, memory consumption on Ubuntu worse by order of magnitude than on Windows 10, trying multiple different and recent versions of python